# Middleware unable to authorize

Tags: node.js, express, react-router, jwt, mern

I am following this Udemy course on MERN stack, and I got stuck when using web tokens and authorizations.

I created an auth.js file that looks like this:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

function auth(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const token = req.cookie.token;

    if(!token){
        res.status(401).json({errorMessage: "Unauthorized 1"});
    }

    const validatedUser = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = validatedUser.id;

    next();
  }
  catch(err) {
    res.status(401).json({errorMessage: "Unauthorized 2"});
  }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

In my snippetRouter.js file, I bring in the auth and attempt to use it in my get router.  As follows:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const { get } = require("mongoose");
const Snippet = require("../models/snippetModel");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

router.get("/", auth, async(req, res) => {
  try{
    console.log(req.user); // <-- stuck here

    const snippets = await Snippet.find();
    res.json(snippets);
  }
  catch(err){
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

Using Insomnia, I am calling the .get router.  I should be able to see the user id in the terminal console, but Insomnia is giving me the "Unauthorized 2" error.

That tells me that something happened within the try block of the auth function on auth.js, but I am not sure how to figure it out. I am following the tutorial exactly as instructed.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
const token = req.cookie.token;
```

should be:

```
const token = req.cookies.token;
```

Because `req.cookie` does not exist, your reference to `req.cookie.token` was throwing and thus you got to the `catch` block.

Two points of advice for the future.  First, when you get an error on your server, always log what that error is.

If you had this:

```
catch(err){
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).send();
}
```

The cause of the error would probably have been obvious because that `err` would have told you what the problem was.

Second, when you have a problem like this that stumps you, add additional logging to see what all the intermediate values are (or set a breakpoint and step through it in the debugger).  You probably would have quickly figured out that you never got past `const token = req.cookie.token;` and then you could log `req.cookie` to see why.  That would have also shown you where the problem was.

---

I presume it goes without saying that some previous step here needed to set the token into the appropriate Insomnia cookie jar so that the token will be present in a cookie.

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I missed that.  I will definitely utilize your recommendation regarding the error.  Thanks again.